# Chrome won't redirect through htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, google-chrome, redirect

I want to redirect all urls without www to the www-version:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.tld$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.tld/$1 [R=301,L]
```

that works for every browser except google chrome with subfolders. That means http://domain.tld is redirected to http://www.domain.tld like it should but when I want to access http://domain.tld/subfolder I get a 'ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED' error in chrome.
Firefox, IE, Safari are working.

Answer (score 0):

I have no definite answer for you, but these few hint may help you :

**idea 1**
Chrome uses google own's DNS, so it might be that it is trying to reach directly the ip host known as www.domain.tld for wich it does'nt find a record.

**Idea 2**

You might want to install [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and run a trace to see exactly what is exchanged between chrome and the internet. This way you'll know if your apache conf is firing the redirect correctly.

I tried typing both adresses in chrome directly : none is recognized by the omnibar (which suggests to me an issue with google dns mirrors)